# Floating action button (Fab) Icon size problems after migrating to sdk 28

Tags: android, android-layout

So the icon size goes too small and aligned far left after migrating to SDK 28 which is weird everything is working tried setting an empty project and just used a floating action button with an icon and after resizing the icon size goes weird like this in the image provided below.

Here is a picture of how it looks :

[image: Preview of the problem]

Tried setting the scale type attribute in the FAB to center and it didn't work also set it to fitcenter and it also did not work.

Here is my floating action button code :

```
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab2"
       android:padding="0dp"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/_63sdp"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/_63sdp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       app:fabSize="auto"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:focusable="true"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_brush"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The brush icon vector XML code :

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#F8F7FF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M7,14c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3 0,1.31 -1.16,2 -2,2 0.92,1.22 2.49,2 4,2 2.21,0 4,-1.79 4,-4 0,-1.66 -1.34,-3 -3,-3zM20.71,4.63l-1.34,-1.34c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0L9,12.25 11.75,15l8.96,-8.96c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41z"/>
</vector>
```

Dimen is a library I'm using to adjust screen sizes but don't worry I also tried without it and the issue is still there.

It only worked well after I added (But it should work without that):

```
fab.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
fab2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Comment: Try app:fabSize="mini"

Comment: Tried it and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if someone is having the same problem :

> Till now there is no good enough XML option to fix the issue (If you
>   know one please post an answer to the question it would be much appreciated )

But programmatically you can do this guys:

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
 fab.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue with the custom `android:layout_width="@dimen/_63sdp"` & `android:layout_height="@dimen/_63sdp"`

Try this use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` & `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/_63sdp"`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_63sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_63sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_white"
        app:fabCustomSize="30dp"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/_30sdp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/_63sdp"
        app:maxImageSize="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Well, I am sure it would work but it will result in the button size being decreased to become too small instead of having the desired button size I need for the screen.

Comment: @AmirEmad you can use `app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/_63sdp"` ti set your required size of your fab also use `app:maxImageSize="50dp"` to change icon size

Comment: One moment testing it now.

Comment: @AmirEmad ok let me know in case of any qiery

Comment: Worked perfectly. The only issue is that I have to set a different max size for each layout since either the icon would be oversized to just fit or undersized. I still wish to know why did Google change it the old way were the icon size would automatically be handled before. Anyway, I tried it with the `app:maxImageSize="@dimen/_30sdp"` and it looked better. Thanks a ton but I still wish to find a solution where it can handle the icon size by itself.

Answer (score 2):

use `app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/_63sdp"` , remove `app:fabSize="auto"` if not works

Comment: Tried this it worked and made the icon in the middle but it was still smaller than the desired button size.

Answer (score 2):

Use maxImageSize attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:fabCustomSize="100dp"
        app:maxImageSize="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_employer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_img" />
```

Use this dependency(**Use this for now**):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Alpha version library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

[Further reading](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: I already use the non-alpha library version. Do you mean I should use the alpha version instead?

Comment: No don't use it.

Comment: Also, wrap content will result in the button size becoming too small.

Answer (score 0):

set the **dimension** attribute like this to avoid this issue :

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:fabSize="normal"
```